# Seq2Seq in Keras for prediction the next element of a sequence of vectors

Tags: python, keras, seq2seq

Excuse me. I am a beginner in neural networks. I have to use seq2seq model in Keras for prediction the next element **x[N]** of a sequence of vectors **x[0], x[1], ..., x[N-1]**.

This sequence of vectors has variable length, that is, *N* is not fixed number. The elements (the vectors) of the sequence have fixed length *m*. That is, my data **x[0], x[1], ..., x[N-1]** have the form

**[x[0,0], x[0,1], ..., x[0,m-1]], [x[1,0], x[1,1], ..., x[1,m-1]], ..., [x[N-1,0], x[N-1,1], ..., x[N-1,m-1]]**

and I have to predict the next vector **x[N]=[x[N,0], x[N,1], ..., x[N,m-1]]**.

Do I understand correctly that the model I need is described with such a snippet code in Keras?

```
data_dim = m

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(1, input_shape=(None, data_dim)))
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Yes, that looks reasonable. The model will take arbitrary length sequence of data_dim and produce in your a single number due to 1 output unit of LSTM.

Answer (score 1):

To build a seq-to-seq model you'd need to use Keras's functional API instead of building a `Sequential()` model. There is a good example of how to do this on the Keras Blog: https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense

encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, num_encoder_tokens))
encoder = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(encoder_inputs)
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, num_decoder_tokens))
decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs,
                                     initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_dense = Dense(num_decoder_tokens, activation='softmax')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
```

Comment: thank you very much for the gear answer. I have a similar question where I need to predict the whole future sequence. More specifically, my question is mentioned in: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/439914/how-to-predict-future-sequence-data?noredirect=1#comment819465_439914 Please let me know if you have any thoughts. I am struggling to find a good start point. Looking forward to hearing from you :)